# PhpStorm Symfony profiler

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

How can I make symfony profiler work in phpstorm? It supposed to be in the status bar, but when I open that window, it always says: "Nothing here". Cache dirs are defined correctly in the configuration, symfony plugin itself works fine. But the profiler never shows information.

[image]

PhpStorm: 8.0.3, Symfony plugin: 0.11.92

Comment: You must activate the symfony2-plugin PHPStorm Per Project for run correctly. I have the same issue in PHPStorm 10.

Comment: Holy crap! I didn't know there's a Symfony Profiler's integration in PHPStorm. :D There's still something new to discover in PHPStorm every day.

Comment: Jakub, I have the same problem with Symfony 3 and PHPStorm 2016.3.2. I have this plugin enabled (version 0.13.136), but still "Nothing here". Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Profiler records are automatically picked up from your cache (i.e from `app/cache/dev/profiler/index.csv`).

1. Ensure you are running server in `dev` env. The profile is collected only in dev mode
2. Check that file exist within your local code.

Do you run the symfony on the same machine that you phpstorm code is located? If no you should condfigure the phpstorm `deployment` to fetch the cache from remote host for you automatically.

3. Ensure you have web profiler enabled for symfony (enabled in your AppKernel and with config)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html

```
web_profiler:
  toolbar: true
```